# How the rt2x00 driver (kernel version 2.6.24) handles scan request

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, driver, wifi

I work with raling rt73 usb device on Ubuntu 8.04 (kernel version 2.6.24) on lpia (Intel Atom) platform. The device is handled by rt2x00 drivers that are part of the kernel. The scan routines are performed incorrect (eg. wrong signal quality and redundant networks are detected). I want to fix these issues, but I cannot  find the place in the driver code where those mentioned values are calculated. Unfortunately neither the driver is exhaustively documented, nor the website of the project provided me with useful information.

I wanted to track how the ioctl commands are executed (e.g. SIOCSIWSCAN or SIOCGIWSCAN commands) but they are not mentioned in the code (`grep SIOCSIWSCAN *` returns nothing). Also the struct, where the scan results are stored (`struct iwreq`) does not exist in the code.

I am fresh to drivers so maybe I am approaching the problem in wrong way. Can you push me in right direction?